# Is there any treatment for adults with talipes calcaneovarus (club foot)?

Tags: treatment, feet

I did a quick research & there seem to be a non-surgery treatment **for babies** with talipes calcaneovarus (club foot) as [quoted from this website](http://patient.info/health/club-foot-congenital-talipes-equinovarus).

> Major surgery was often a common treatment used. However, the results of medical research studies have shown that other treatments without major surgery, particularly a treatment known as the Ponseti method, seem to give good long-term results for most children. The Ponseti method is now the preferred treatment by most orthopaedic surgeons throughout the world.

Is there anything similar **for adults**?

see also http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/valgus